# using ubuntu core on a raspberry pi as a systems integrator

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, oem

Our company is planning to use embedded raspberry pi boards with Ubuntu core in a product integration.  After going through initial setup of the raspberry pi unit, I'm very concerned that this setup process is tying a personal account (mine) to the device that will ultimately be imaged over and over and deployed to many different customer sites.

I'm trying to understand what the process is for doing this setup/configuration in a way that is not going to tie my identity to these devices long term.  Do we just setup some generic systems account (and e-mail at our company) to do this or are we violating the usage agreement somehow by approaching things this way?

If anyone has tips or pointers on how to avoid what is obviously a personal identity / configuration approach for doing this setup in an OEM/Integrator type of situation, info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your PROTOTYPE Ubuntu Core system will indeed be tied to your Ubuntu One login. During development, you will change (or eliminate) that login. It's as simple as `deluser your_login --remove-home`. Your final product, which you copy into your devices, should have whatever login security (if it has a login at all) that you desire. Remember to generate a random UUID for each device.

Comment: Thanks, good information to have.